# Python question elemetree about boolean operators

Tags: python, xml

is there a way to use boolean operators in the xpath of a findall command. For example:
`root.findall("./example/[value='a' or 'b']/example2"`

Comment: What is `root`? You need to at least indicate if you're using ElementTree or BeautifulSoup or lxml or whatever.

Comment: root is  ```root = tree.getroot()```

Comment: ElementTree? You cannot make us guess!

Comment: Yes, is in the title

Comment: ElementTree has only basic support for xpath afaik. You may have better luck using lxml.

Comment: BTW, the correct syntax for XPATH would be `[value='a' or value='b']` so you may want to try that first.

Comment: It could be `./example[value='a' or value='b']` or `./example/*[value='a' or value='b']` for a doc containing `example/value` or `value` as a descendant of `example`

Answer (score 0):

Could not get the XPATH to work in `ElementTree` but was able to get it working in `lxml`.

It was not clear if `value` was an attribute or a child of `example` so I show both.

```py
import lxml.etree as ET

data = '''\
<abc>
    <example value="a">
        <example2>foo</example2>
    </example>
    <example value="b">
        <example2>bar</example2>
    </example>
    <example value="x">
        <example2>not this</example2>
    </example>
</abc>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for e in root.xpath('./example[@value="a" or @value="b"]/example2'):
    print(e.text)

data2 = '''\
<abc>
    <example>
        <value>a</value>
        <example2>abc</example2>
    </example>
    <example>
        <value>b</value>
        <example2>def</example2>
    </example>
    <example>
        <value>not this</value>
        <example2>xyz</example2>
    </example>
</abc>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(data2)
for e in root.xpath('./example[value="a" or value="b"]/example2'):
    print(e.text)
```